# solid delta and inverted delta symbol in html

Tags: html, extended-ascii

I need to display the following two symbols in an email

1. solid upward delta : something
   like ▲
2. solid downward delta : ▼

But i cannot use extended-ascii set, because it causes problems in the unix system where my email templates are generated.

Is there any html code, or any other code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using the unicode values as character entities, as follows:

```
&#9650;     (for ▲)
&#9660;     (for ▼)
```

This works for me, but it's worth testing a lot because support in different clients may be quite variable...